Azure Function: Did not find functions with language [dotnet-isolated]
I cannot succed in starting my Azure Function. I got the following error:
[2024-04-25T09:22:29.421Z] Found 
 C:\Users\gdifronzo\source_C#\AE.Resp.Device.Sync\ 
 AE.Resp.Device.Sync\AE.Resp.Device.Sync\AE 
.Resp.Device.Sync.csproj.    Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-04-25T09:22:30.766Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 
'd5c1ddb1-1e25-406a-b64c-ef69bf086ab4'.

[2024-04-25T09:22:30.768Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Did not find functions with 
language [dotnet-isolated].
[2024-04-25T09:22:30.786Z] Failed to stop host instance '8db57ba1-9d37-44cd-a3d9- 
e6e01699e700'.
[2024-04-25T09:22:30.788Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: The host has not yet started.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

My local.settings.json is the following:
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
 "Values": {
 "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
"FhirServerUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net",
"TimeTriggerSchedule": "0 */5 * * *",
"MaximumExecutionTime": 21600,
"MongoDbConnectionString": "mongodb+srv://xxxxxxxxxxx",
"MongoDbThumbprint": "xxxxxxxx"
  }
}

Azurite local emulator is on. My Program.cs in the Azure Function project is:
IHostBuilder builder = new HostBuilder().ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication();

 var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
    .Build();

X509Certificate2 mongoCertificate;
 string mongoConnectionString = configuration.GetValue<string> 
 ("MongoDbConnectionString") 
  ?? 
 throw new CertificateNotFoundException("Unable to load configuration with key 
'MongoDbConnectionString'");

try
{
  mongoCertificate = 
Utils.LoadCertificate(configuration.GetRequiredSection("MongoDbThumbprint").Value);
}
catch
{
  throw;
}

MongoDBService mongoDBService = new(mongoConnectionString, mongoCertificate);

builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
  services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
  services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
  services.AddSingleton<IDeviceSyncService, DeviceSyncService>();
  services.AddSingleton(mongoDBService.CreateRepository<ExecutionParameters> 
 ("deviceSync"));
 });

IHost host = builder.Build();

host.Run();

The functios is:
private readonly ILogger _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<DeviceSyncFunction>();
private readonly IDeviceSyncService _deviceSyncService = deviceSyncService;

[Function("DeviceSyncFunction")]
 public void Run([TimerTrigger("%TimerExpression%", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo 
timerInfo)
{

try
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.UtcNow} 
  UTC");

    _deviceSyncService.GenerateDevices();

    _logger.LogInformation($"Timer trigger function terminated at: {DateTime.UtcNow} 
  UTC");
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException opex)
  {
    _logger.LogWarning(opex, opex.Message);
  }
  catch (FhirOperationException ex)
  {
    _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    _logger.LogCritical(ex, ex.Message);
  }
 }

And the project file .cproj is:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <None Include="local.settings.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>     
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference 
    Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http"Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference 
    Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" 
   Version="1.2.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" 
    Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" 
      Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" 
   Version="1.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
 <ProjectReference 
   Include="..\AE.Resp.Device.Sync.Model\AE.Resp.Device.Sync.Model.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference 
 Include="..\AE.Resp.Device.Sync.Service\AE.Resp.Device.Sync.Service.csproj" />

 <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
 </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>  

</Project>

I can't even figure out what's happening. As I said, azurite local emulator is on, I don't have any problem with it. ChatGPT says that the configuration is correct. I'm trying to troubleshoot, but I cannot find anything clear. When I try to start-up another Azure Function with the same settings and dependencies (I've copied and past dependencies on project file and also the Program.cs and local.settings are similar), I succed. So the problem seem not an hidden wrong settings on my local computer. Any idea?


Delete the bin and obj folders and rebuilding your function project.
Rebuild and test the function again.

I have tested your code with the same settings in my environment, and it worked as expected.
Move local.settings.json code snippet to ItemGroup of host.json in .csproj:
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>  
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Console Response:
[2024-04-25T11:26:48.597Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 30604) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-04-25T11:26:48.721Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Function1: timerTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-04-25T11:26:49.467Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-04-25T16:56:49.4150207+05:30', Id=957b8027-bef6-4bc4-af26-438c96c1bef8)
[2024-04-25T11:26:49.471Z] Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: RunOnStartup
[2024-04-25T11:26:49.748Z] Timer trigger function terminated at: 4/25/2024 11:26:49 AMUTC
[2024-04-25T11:26:49.748Z] Timer trigger function executed at: 4/25/2024 11:26:49 AM UTC
[2024-04-25T11:26:49.801Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=957b8027-bef6-4bc4-af26-438c96c1bef8, Duration=368ms)


I was facing this issue as well. I had the following reference in my .csproj file:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />

When i start my function it was showing this error message and I had recently updated .Net framework to .Net6. I updated the above package to the latest version i.e. 4.6.0, deleted lib and obj folders and built the project again. After starting it again, it worked fine.
